# Accessing enum name in PowerShell

Tags: rest, powershell, enums, office365, sharepoint-online

I am working on PowerShell a script and I've been having a difficult time using enum types. I perform a REST call to SharePoint Online to get information about a particular group.

```
$group = Invoke-SPORestMethod -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site/_api/web/RoleAssignments/GetByPrincipalId(8)?`$expand=RoleDefinitionBindings"
$group.RoleDefinitionBindings.results[0].RoleTypeKind
```

It returns an int, RoleTypeKind, that is an enum in  `[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleType]`. I'm having difficulty accessing the name property of the assciated enum value. I'm currently doing it like this but it seems horribly wrong:

```
function getGroupPermissionKind([int]$roleType){
    #https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.roletype.aspx
    [Enum]::GetValues([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleType]) | foreach {
        $Name = $_
        $Value = ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleType]::$_).value__
        if ($Value -eq $roleType){
            return $Name
        }
    }
}
```

Knowing that `$group.RoleDefinitionBindings.results[0].RoleTypeKind` returns the proper int of the enum, how can I more directly access the name of the enum rather than with the seemingly janky implementation I've come up with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know you can just use casting:

```
[System.AttributeTargets]4096
```

This results in

```
Delegate
```

If you need plain string, call `ToString()` as follows

```
([System.AttributeTargets]4096).ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question. Do you want to create a reverse mapping of the integer values to the respective role names, so you can get the names by their integer value? That can be achieved with a hashtable, like this:

```
$map = @{}
[enum]::GetValues([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleType]) | ForEach-Object {
  $map[$_.value__] = $_.ToString()
}
```

The `value__` property returns the numeric value of an enumeration item, while the `ToString()` method returns its stringified value, i.e. its name.

With that map you can look up the name like this:

```
$map[$group.RoleDefinitionBindings.results[0].RoleTypeKind]
```

Comment: I do want to do a reverse lookup, but I feel that my implementation is terrible. There has to be a native way to do it that I'm not grasping.

Comment: Umm... I just posted one? Of course, if you already have a `RoleType` object instead of just the numeric value you should be able to get the name by invoking its `ToString()` method as suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38568919/1630171).